# Display a value from a Database with a function by using SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, function

So i'm on a project which is a quiz website for french medical student and I'm using Wordpress to develop it. I'm having trouble with something :
I want, through a function, to display a value on the home page. This value is how many quizzes are available. To do that, I know that in my database I have a list of my quizzes which are sort by an id. You probably guessed that I want to use the list ID to know the number of quizzes.

To summarize :

- I need to select the last id from a row in a table from a database
- To integrate that value in a function
- Function that I will transform in shortcode for elementory

My problem : I tried a lot of things but nothing work, I searched during hours and the "final" code that I have is that :

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","db"); // I tried in the function, outside, and in a "db.php"

function wpc_elementor_shortcode($conn) >Tried with $conn, $db, $dbc, ...
    {
        $sql = "SELECT entry_id FROM wp_frmt_form_entry ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 1"; >The only thing that I know it's okay
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        echo("entry_id"); >a desperate attempt to display the result, tried with while fetch_assoc, $result, ...
    }
add_shortcode( 'get_number_qcm', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode');
```

I'm stuck at this point and I hope that someone will help me to solve that problem, thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want the count of items. You can't rely on the insert id for that. SELECT count(entry_id) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tested your code and here are my findings**

- It is better to have a separate file for short-codes Within your
  themes i.e. ***themes<theme_name>\shortcodes.php*** create file if not
  already present
- Include it in ***\functions.php***

//shortcodes

```
require_once( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'shortcodes.php' );
```

**In shortcodes.php**

```
function wpc_elementor_shortcode() {
    $conn=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","db");
    $sql = "SELECT entry_id FROM wp_frmt_form_entry ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();
    return $result['entry_id']; 
}

add_shortcode( 'get_number_qcm', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode');
```

Now, you can use **[get_number_qcm]** for the required **entry_id** value

***NOTE:***

*you can use this as a quick solution but for **$conn** being used in this way is not at all a good way to connect to DB securely in **shortcodes.php** file, instead please use proper connection object and design pattern for database connection object.*

Comment: Thanks !! I take note of your advice and your code is working properly, thank you very much for that help, i'm very grateful